# New VM on Windows 7 Virtual PC cannot access host's DVD Drive

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I have a brand new clean machine with Windows 7 Professional 64bit and I've installed the patch that adds Windows Virtual PC (Windows6.1-KB958559-x64). 
I then go to Windows Virtual PC, create a new Virtual Machine. As soon as go to settings and try to map the VM DVD drive to the host's DVD drive I get "File may be in use by another process or you may not have sufficient access privilege".
I am an administrator in that box...

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's embarrassing... All I needed to do was to run it as Administrator and I had access to my DVD Drive.